# Perform multiple tasks at once iOS

Tags: swift

I would like my app to perform multiple functions at the same time instead of starting one once the other is completed. Is this possible and if so how should I be doing this?

Comment: Are these long running tasks? If so, you should be doing these in separate threads. Here is a link to get you started with multithreading in iOS: http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial

Comment: If these complete quickly there is little advantage to performing them concurrently. The decrease in clock time to complete will be dependent on the number of CPU cores and other CPU requests from the OS. The basic thing is to measure, if there is not a performance problem then don't do it, doing it falls under the heading of pre-mature optimization and is to be avoided. Kent Beck: "Do the simplest thing that could possibly work."

Comment: The tasks do not complete quickly so I am hoping to run two at once to reduce this time. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A great way to accomplish this is by using `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue`. They are fairly easy-to-use yet powerful (dependencies, cancellation, priorities...) high-level APIs over GCD.

Here is a great tutorial on how to use them: http://www.raywenderlich.com/76341/use-nsoperation-nsoperationqueue-swift